# Inserting dates from django templates into url tag

Tags: python, django

I have this calendar app view that requires the current year and month, and is used across approximately 1/4 of the site so I was hoping to create a `{% url %}` for it that wouldn't required updating the context everywhere.

I inherit a template with a JS script containing the following:

`var url = "{% url 'companies:deliverers:deliverer-calendar-view' pk=company.pk slug=company.slugged_name year=now 'Y' month=now 'M' %}"`

I was hoping to plug the `year` and `month` `kwargs` by using the standard template tags, but this give be an error:

```
Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()!
```

I also tried doing:

```
"{% url 'companies:deliverers:deliverer-calendar-view' pk=company.pk slug=company.slugged_name year=now'Y' month=now'M' %}"
```

But this gives me:

```
Could not parse the remainder: ''Y'' from 'now'Y''
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need at least a date variable from the context. Then you can get away with:

```
{% with year=my_date|date:'Y' month=my_date|date:'M' %}
  {% url 'companies:deliverers:deliverer-calendar-view' pk=company.pk slug=company.slugged_name year=year month=month %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking @Lucas Moeskops logic into account, I was able to develop a better solution:

```
{% now "Y" as YEAR %}
{% now "m" as MONTH %}
var url = "{% url 'companies:deliverers:deliverer-calendar-view' pk=company.pk slug=company.slugged_name year=YEAR month=MONTH %}"
```

Using this method you never have to hack the `context_data` for a bunch of views... pretty nice :).

Comment: Ah :-) I tried that but I guess that only works from Django 1.9, I tried in 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import datetime and do datetime.now()... You can pass that to a view through the context.